# Centering div and a float right div

Tags: css, layout, centering

I have a DIV which I want to always keep in the center of the screen even when the browser is resized. Also there is a floating right DIV which shouldn't overlap the center DIV.

Chrome is causing lots of problems with either center going off the screen at the left side or the right floating DIV overlapping the center DIV.

**CSS**

```
.center {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 650px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;   
}
.right {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #808080;  
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;  
    float: right;   
}
body {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="center">center</div>
```

Comment: what version of chrome are you using? I am using chromium 18.0.1025.168 and it looks fine

Comment: Test it in chrome 19, looks good: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wLGj7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    .center
    {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        background-color: #808080;
        width: 50%;
        height: 200px;
        margin:0 auto;


    }

    .right
    {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        background-color: #808080;

        width: 25%;
        height: 200px;

        float: right;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found only 1 issue, and its the right `div` overlapping the center `div`, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wLGj7/3/) is a possible solution to that, you just needed to add `position: relative;` to the class of the center `div`

**CSS**

```
.center
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 650px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.right
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
}
body
{
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}​
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me so long as the content never overlaps:

```
.right {
 float: right;
 min-width: 0;   
 border: 1px solid blue;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.center {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

If that's the issue, I think you have to explore options where the content font-size shrinks as the page shrinks, which I think is only available with js reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="center">center</div>
<div class="right">right</div>


.center {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 650px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;   
    display:block;

}
.right {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #0f0;  
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;  
    float: right;  
    margin-top:10px;    
    display:block;
}
body {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```